# Nvidia 460 driver doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have the following laptop: Asus ROG G733QS with an **RTX 3080 laptop** GPU and I tried installing the 460 Nvidia driver, but when the OS starts, it only shows a blinking cursor.

Could you please help me?

This is the output of `sudo lshw` for the GPU:

```
*-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:36 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:fb000000-fc0fffff ioport:f800000000(size=17213423616)
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: NVIDIA Corporation
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: iomemory:f80-f7f iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:f800000000-fbffffffff memory:fc00000000-fc01ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: NVIDIA Corporation
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:99 memory:fc080000-fc083fff
```

Comment: How did you install the driver?

Comment: Using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-460`

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: Yes, from the BIOS

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: `Linux 5.8.0-44-generic`

Comment: It should work. It is either some driver bug, or it was not properly installed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've tried installing it multiple times, both with the command above and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and both on Ubuntu and on Linux Mint, but with no success :( Do you think it's worth trying to install from "source" (the .run file from Nvidia's website)?

Comment: You can try it, but it is unlikely to help. It is the same driver but better packed.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the AMD chipset.

Comment: Maybe if you attempted to use Vulkan instead?

Comment: From my understanding, Vulkan is a low-level API that is implemented by Nvidia through their drivers, but there aren't different drivers for Vulkan, right?